# Publishing .Net Web App does not copy certain files

Tags: .net, deploying

There are certain images & swf files that are used in the project, but they are not added to the project (Meaning, the Solution Explorer does not show them).

When I try to use the Build->Publish option in VS2008, those images & swf files are not published.

1. Do I have to necessarily add them to the project in order to publish them?
2. Isn't there any better way? Because it is easy to miss adding of certain type of files (images, swf, etc). For eg. If you rename an image file outside of the project and forget to update in the project then publish will fail again.

Thanks. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - you need to add them to the project
2. You could use a different method to publish if you like, but you need to add them to your solution to get them published this way.

Answer (score 1):

To publish the files you have to add all the files you wish to the solution,

Make sure that in your solution explorer you select the option to show all files this will make finding everything easier.

Also remember that with some files types .pdf for example you will need to change the Build Action of each file to 'Content' and the 'copy to output dirctory' to 'copy always' other wise it wont publish.